# Carousel view being small on load

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Two developers tried to solve an issue with a Carousel on my website.
Basically, Carousel loads but it is smaller than what it should be.
This problem occurs on Mac.
Fyi: Enlarging the screen from only an inch put the Carousel on its normal format.
Also, the Carousel, whatever the size of the screen Always loads on the bottom of the page. [image]

Enlarging manually the screen put the Carousel on its normal format:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your Help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. In its current form, your question is not answerable. In order for anyone to help you, you need to create a [mcve] of your problem. Nobody will ever be able to tell you what to change or where in your code from looking at a picture with the output of your code. Without any intention of being harsh, if what I just stated doesn't make sense to you, you are in the wrong place to ask your question.

Comment: Hi Andrei,Very well, I will more details asap. Thanks for your thought, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because at the time the carousel initializes, not all `css` scripts and images are loaded and. This causes the carousel to be adjusted to a different visual state of the page. By resizing the window, you force the carousel to re-initialize, so it gets the right dimensions.

A simple solution is to find the carousel's `refresh` function in it's documentation and trigger it with a slight delay after the page is fully loaded.

For example:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    // refresh Carousel.
  },500)
});
```